# How to apply css for a div pattern

Tags: css

I've two divs, suppose the first one is `edit-text-field-12`, and other is of the form `edit-text-field-12-23`. And these numbers changes, I would like apply different css for divs. Is it possible to do in CSS.

I want to apply background color red for all the div following the pattern `edit-text-field-12` and background color blue for the divs with the pattern `edit-text-field-12-23`.

Is it possible?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="edit-text-field-12" value="12">
<input type="checkbox" id="edit-text-field-12-23" value="12-23">
<input type="checkbox" id="edit-text-field-12-46" value="12-46">
<input type="checkbox" id="edit-text-field-12-39" value="12-39">

<input type="checkbox" id="edit-text-field-17" value="17">
<input type="checkbox" id="edit-text-field-17-21" value="17-21">
<input type="checkbox" id="edit-text-field-17-34" value="17-34">
```

There are inputs of type check boxes. On change of another field this list is populated. The checkbox with the pattern `edit-text-field-*` are parents, and the checkbox with the pattern 'edit-text-field-*-*' are child elements. I want to show it in 2 different backgrounds.

Comment: try .first-div-className + div {} . It will help if your first div has classname which is not changing

Answer (score 3):

**SOLUTION AT BOTTOM**

---

---

Assuming these are **ids**, you can select them **all** like so:

```css
[id^="edit-text-field-"] {
    /* YOUR CSS */
}
```

This would select `edit-text-field-11`, `edit-text-field-12`, `edit-text-field-12-23` etc.

To be more **specific** with this **partial selector**, you could add the 12 to the end etc, eg.

```css
[id^="edit-text-field-12"] {
    /* YOUR CSS */
}
```

This would select `edit-text-field-12`, `edit-text-field-12-23`, but not `edit-text-field-11`.

For the **individual** ids, the syntax is as follows:

```css
#edit-text-field-12 {
    /* YOUR CSS */
}
```

For further reading, see [W3Schools CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), which explains all the possible CSS selectors available to you.

---

---

In **response** to the question edit:

```css
#edit-text-field-12 {
    /* YOUR CSS for the first bit */
}
[id^="edit-text-field-12-"] {
    /* YOUR CSS for the other bits */
}
```

Replace the 12 with 17 for the second set etc.

You can't select the parts with 12 being any number, as there is **no wildcard** value in CSS (eg. `edit-text-field-*-`), so you'll have to repeat the above, you can use commas so you don't **repeat the styles**.

```css
#edit-text-field-12,
#edit-text-field-17 {
    /* YOUR CSS for the first bit */
}
[id^="edit-text-field-12-"],
[id^="edit-text-field-17-"] {
    /* YOUR CSS for the other bits */
}
```

---

---

A **solution** for this, as the **inputs** have **values**, is to use the values to detect which type they are.

Doing this, you could select everything like so:

```css
[id^="edit-text-field-"]:not([value*="-"]) {
    /* YOUR CSS for the first bit */
    background: #f44336;
}
[id^="edit-text-field-"][value*="-"] {
    /* YOUR CSS for the other bits */
    background: #1976d2;
}
```

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra Edited to respond to your edit, please accept my answer if it helps :)

Comment: That 12 can be any digit, I'm sorry it didn't help me much

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra Wildcards don't exist in CSS, so you'll have to repeat it for each 12 etc. I'll edit the answer to explain.

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra I've edited my answer to now include a working solution based on the value attribute of the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

you an use a [partial selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp) as below.

```
div[class^="edit-text-field-"] {

}
```

**EDIT:** Jquery Solution

Since you didnt mention clearly on if you are trying to change the background color of the div or the input element, I assume you want to wrap each of the input in a div and color them.

Below is the sample snippet.

Key points.

**1.** I have used [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) on all the inputs to filter out only the single digit id's and double digit id's using `regex`

`^edit-text-field-\d+$` -> makes sure it selects id's like `edit-text-field-12`, `edit-text-field-17`

`^edit-text-field-\d+-\d+$` -> makes sure it selects id's like `edit-text-field-12-23`, `edit-text-field-17-21` etc.

**2.** Once the elements are filtered I am wrapping them using `wrap` with a div and appropriate class name to get the background color.

Hope this is helpful.

```js
var singleNumberPatternElements = [];
var doubleNumberPatternElements = [];

$('input').filter(function(){
 return this.id.match(/^edit-text-field-\d+$/g);
}).wrap('<div class="singleNumber"/>');

$('input').filter(function(){
 return this.id.match(/^edit-text-field-\d+-\d+$/g);
}).wrap('<div class="doubleNumber"/>');
```

```css
.singleNumber{
background-color:blue; 
}

.doubleNumber{
  background-color:Red; 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="edit-text-field-12" value="12">
<input type="checkbox" id="edit-text-field-12-23" value="12-23">
<input type="checkbox" id="edit-text-field-12-46" value="12-46">
<input type="checkbox" id="edit-text-field-12-39" value="12-39">

<input type="checkbox" id="edit-text-field-17" value="17">
<input type="checkbox" id="edit-text-field-17-21" value="17-21">
<input type="checkbox" id="edit-text-field-17-34" value="17-34">
```

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra your new requirement cannot be done using CSS, it can be done using Javascript / Jquery

Comment: How may I know?

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra is it the checkbox you want to apply css to or the divs? I dont see div's in your code but in the question you mention about div

Comment: @Reddy It can be done in CSS. See my answer. Using JS is not what the question asked...

Comment: @MattCowley Thanks for not downvoting as the OP didnt ask for JS solution, But if you read the comments above I did tell him that it cant be done using CSS but can be done with JS and the OP asked me how so I posted a solution. Now coming to your solution, I like the fact you are using the `value` attribute, But what if the value is changed to something else? No doubt your solution works as is given the HTML doesn't change, But what if the value changes? So I concentrated only on the `id` field as suggested by the OP. You are not wrong, Also I feel I am not wrong either, what do you think? :)

Comment: @Reddy Your solution works if he plans to change the values, but based on the fact the values are the same as the ids kinda, I banked on them not changing. So both answers work :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS3 partial selector

```css
div[class^="edit-text-field-"]{
  width:100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="edit-text-field-12">abc</div>
<div class="edit-text-field-12-23">def</div>
```